# "ReportItems!Tablix.Value" can use in page footer but page header can't use

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdlc, ssrs-tablix, rdl

On a textbox of Page Header and Footer, I need to display value which get from The Tablix.

[image]

In tablix has a one column and It's bound with A Table.
(.DatasetName = "ATable")

```
       A 
_______________
      ID
  CUSTOMER_CODE
```

But I need to display a name of Customer which it can get from B Table.

```
       B 
_______________
 CUSTOMER_CODE
 CUSTOMER_NAME
```

So a cell in the Tablix use this expression

```
    =Lookup(Fields!CUSTOMER_CODE.Value,Fields!CUSTOMER_CODE.Value,Fields!CUSTOMER_NAME.Value, "BTable")
```

This step. I can get a value from a cell of the my  tablix(in body).

Next, I need to display getting value on header and footer.
by using expression in header and footer

```
   =ReportItems!txtInTablix.Value
```

**It can use in footer but header is error.**

Below figure is result. It'sn't show any error message expect "#Error" in textbox header.

[image]

Comment: In header and footer you have added `Text Boxes` and you trying to apply this expression to `Text Boxes`? You have done something wrong, because no care where It is - on header or footer.

Comment: Oh, I see. First, at Page Header I put textbox in bigger textbox. So It error.

Comment: Your welcome and good luck

Comment: I am sorry. It's not work. I don't understand. When I put textbox on header without any textbox , without any rectangle. It's not error.

But when I put it on textbox or Rectangle it will error.
What should I do?

Comment: This is my stupid. I use =reportitems!txtCUSTOMER_NAME .  It wrong because I must use =reportitems!txtCUSTOMER_NAME.Value instead.

Comment: @ThanapipatPacharatanakoson You can answer your question and mark it as read after 48 hours. It is good to know an answer is solved. In future if any one facing similar issue they can lookup your answer.